# How to gray selection highlight when NatTable not in focus

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

Some lists and tables gray out their selection when they lose keyboard focus.

In the presence of multiple lists/tables, this helps communicate to the user which selection is active.

**Is there an easy way to do this with NatTable?**

The best I've come up with so far is to flip between different attributes for `DisplayMode.SELECT` as focus comes and goes -- but I'm not sure I can do that after `NatTable.configure()` has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change configuration attributes dynamically after `NatTable#configure()` has been called. That is a common approach for dynamic changes. Another approach would be to configure a selection style for a special label and apply that label only in case the table is active. This approach can be seen in this example.

https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_500_Layers/_505_Selection/_5054_SelectionProviderExample.java

Answer (score 0):

I have this working, after @DirkFauth's answer. This answer includes some specifics.

After the table has been configured with `NatTable.configure()`, you can modify the configuration not with `NatTable.addConfiguration(IConfiguration)`, but instead by calling `IConfiguration.configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry)`. For example:

```
  myConfiguration.configureRegistry( myTable.getConfigRegistry() )
```

Within that implementation of configureRegistry(), you can set the style for selected and anchor cells:

```
    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE,
          selectedStyle, DisplayMode.SELECT, GridRegion.BODY);

    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE,
          anchorStyle, DisplayMode.SELECT,
          SelectionStyleLabels.SELECTION_ANCHOR_STYLE);
```

When the table is inactive, `selectedStyle` and `anchorStyle` can be modified clones of their usual setting. For example:

```
private static Color myInactiveColor = ...;

public static Style makeInactiveBodyCellStyleFrom(@Nonnull Style style) {
    Style rv = style.clone();

    rv.setAttributeValue( CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR,
        myInactiveColor );

    return rv;
}
```

Similar work can be done for the styles of selected row and column headers.